# How to use qprocess to read output in real time while running the file

Tags: qt, qprocess

I am a beginner in qt. It would be very helpful if this problem solved.
I would like to use QProcess to execute the file and show the real time output to the QTextviewer. 
The file cannot stop running unless you press ctrl c in terminal command line. Otherwise, the file works well on terminal in linux. 
The main problem occured was : the process did start by qt, however, I didn't see any output.

I try signal(readyReadStandardOutput) and slot. When I add waitforfinished(), the GUI will freezed.

```
if(!process)
{
    process = new QProcess (this);
}

process -> setWorkingDirectory("mydir");
connect(process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(logRead()));
connect(process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()), this, SLOT(readError()));
process -> start("./file");
process -> setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);

if(false == peocess-> waitForStarted())
{
    ui -> textBrowser->append("the process cannot be called");
}else{
    ui -> textBrowser->append("the process can be called"); 
}
```

textBrowser did show "the process can be called".

```
void Dialog::logRead()
{
     QProcess *process = dynamic_cast<QProcess *>( sender() );

if (process){
  ui->textBrowser->append( p->readAllStandardOutput() );  
}
```

I dont know why I CANNOT output text in real time, even I didnt get any output!! Any suggestion? thank you!

Comment: Off topic but... from the [`QProcess::setProcessChannelMode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setProcessChannelMode): `"This mode will be used the next time start() is called"`.  So calling `setProcessChannelMode` after `start` probably won't have the desired effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem, must be in a different part of your app. My minimal reproducible examples works like expected.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextBrowser>
#include <QProcess>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    auto process = new QProcess;
    auto view = new QTextBrowser;
    process->setWorkingDirectory("C:/Temp");
    QObject::connect(process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [process,view]() {
        auto output=process->readAllStandardOutput();
        view->append(output);
    });
    QObject::connect(process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardError, [process,view]() {
        auto output=process->readAllStandardError();
        view->append(output);
    });
    process->start("MyProgram.exe");
    process->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);

    process->waitForStarted();
    qDebug() << process->error();
    view->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. After I try again it works but it is not real time message, it will have a about half minute delay.

Comment: @LankoKuo: Maybe your program does not flush its output. There is for example a difference between `std::cout << "Hello\n"; ` and `std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;`. This is something you can backcheck.